# Android PdfRenderer throws SecurityException - cannot create document with error 4

Tags: android, runtimeexception, pdfrenderer, android-securityexception

I'm trying to render some pages using PdfRenderer android api. Some of my users started seeing this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1337, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/Jul-Aug-2016statement.pdf }} to activity {converter.dassem.com.fileconverter/converter.dassem.com.fileconverter.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: cannot create document. Error: 4
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3949)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3992)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1543)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5776)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: cannot create document. Error: 4
    at android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer.<init>(PdfRenderer.java:153)
```

There is nothing in documentation about error 4 although it does say that if the pdf if encrypted with password the security exception will get thrown.
The error occurrs when creating the PdfRenderer from uri.

So is anyone aware of what exactly error 4 means?

Thanks

Comment: post yout `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: I can assure you that it contains all the necessary permissions to read and write to external storage

Comment: What is the device api you are trying to run it in? Because from API 24(Android M) onward you need to ask for permission at runtime

Comment: It's running on the 21 to 23 API, but I did not reproduce it myself - my users did. I do not think this is the problem because the problem occurrs on API 21 as well.

Comment: @JohnSmith : Were you ever able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @JohnSmith Are you able to solve this issue?